# Does SChannel support TLS 1.3 ? Need help w.r.t example client/server programs in C/C++ for implementing TLS 1.3 using SChannel?

Tags: c++, winapi, cryptoapi, windows-11, schannel

Does SChannel support TLS 1.3 ? I need help with regard to example client/server programs in C/C++ for implementing TLS 1.3 using SChannel.

I found `SChannel.h` defines `SP_PROT_TLS1_3_CLIENT` as `0x00002000`, etc.
But the `grbitEnabledProtocols` field of [`SCHANNEL_CRED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/schannel/ns-schannel-schannel_cred) does not mention anything about TLS 1.3.

I was unable to find any other information on the Internet to document whether SChannel supports TLS 1.3 or not.

Comment: It has been a long time. Have you solved your problem？

Answer (score 1):

[SCH_CREDENTIALS - Win32 apps | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/schannel/ns-schannel-sch_credentials)

SChannel support TLS1.3, In order to use TLS 1.3 with schannel, you should use the SCH_CREDENTIALS structure with AcquireCredentialsHandle().

The SCHANNEL_CRED structure has been deprecated. Starting with Windows 10, 1809 (October 2018 Update), you should use SCH_CREDENTIALS.